# VMWare Guest Can't Connect to Host Server

Tags: linux, macos, vmware, linux-mint, vmware-player

I'm running OS X Sierra in VMWare Player on top of Linux Mint 18. I can ping Linux but it won't connect to my server through the browser. I have a separate machine with a test server set up on the same local network. I can reach that one via the browser but not the server on the host. I am trying to connect using IPv4 if that's relevant.

I have tried using 'Bridged', 'NAT' and 'Host Only' to no avail.

Is there some sort of Mac firewall keeping me from connecting with the host?

Any ideas of how to fix?

Edit:

A partial fix [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301039/vmware-guest-web-server-not-reachable-from-host)...
I can specify an IP address to the server in the source code (node) but this is obviously sub optimal as the IP addresses are dynamically assigned. This works. I can view it in the guest browser but I have to manually specify the IP address on both ends. How do I get the guest to see the 'localhost' of the host? Essentially I don't want to have to look up my IP address every time I reconnect to my network and change the code to suit.

Edit:

I have another VM guest with Windows 10 running in it with the same issue so it is at least not Mac specific. It is probably something directly related to VMWare.

Comment: This is a question for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) as it's not directly related to programming and appears to be server related.

Comment: @tadman - I agree it is server related but it is more vmware related I suspect and there is no vmware.stackexchange.com. I think the community of Stack Exchange is more suited to handle the question.

Comment: It's either that or [Super User](http://superuser.com). This is infrastructure/networking related, not programming per-se. That question from 2009 should have been moved off-site, but back then things were significantly more casual as those other sites were still too new to get responses quickly.

Comment: @tadman - https://superuser.com/questions/1067015/how-to-reach-vmware-host-from-guest-without-changing-ip-address-all-the-time - a very similar question... no one seems to know over there either.

Comment: Can you ping something like `8.8.8.8` from inside macOS? Bridged + DHCP assigned address should work best, but NAT also works *if* your Linux firewall isn't too restrictive.

Comment: @tadman - Yes, I can ping 8.8.8.8. I am using Bridged. I don't think it is the Linux firewall. I can reach my Linux server from another local machine (not the VM). The only place I can't reach it from is the VMWare guest.

Comment: You need to do some more diagnostics here. In any case, Super User might be a better place to ask. This is OS related.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bridged network type for the VM.
Try temporary disable local VM OS X firewall:

```
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setglobalstate=off
```

Temorary disable local server firewall rules:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
```

List if IP address of the VM On OS X used same network as your server:

```
ifconfig
```

List local server IP address used, it should be from same network as VM IP:

```
ifconfig
```

If all firewall rules disabled and both machines (VM OS X and local server) from the same subnet then you should able to ping VM IP address from local server. If addresses from different subnets then use statically assigned IP in the VM OS X or change DHCP assign into your router (that assign IPs if any), you can check MAC address of VM network interface and set it to assign right IP address in the router if any and possible there.